# Declare a new instance of a class that implements a interface

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub LoadJobs()
    Dim thisContract As iOutboundContract
    Dim results = From type In System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetTypes()
                  Where GetType(iOutboundContract).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                  Select type
    For Each outboundContract In results
        If outboundContract.Name <> "iOutboundContract" Then
            thisContract = New outboundContract ' <- This line isn't real.  This is what I want to do.
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

In the above procedure, I am able to enumerate a for each to find all classes that implements a specific Interface.  Now I want to declare a variable for each of those classes that implements the contract.  For some reason I am failing to put the appropriate words in a google search.

Comment: `.net reflection create instance of type` would give you a lot of search results, for example [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)

Comment: Reflection is costly. One shall not use reflection lightly, or just because it's cool. You have to understand the mechanisms underneath. Besides, your code looks wrong. From the `Type` instances, you shall call for Activator.CreateInstance directly, since your types within results already implements the `IOutboundContract` interface. Make sure that you call the intended constructor for each of the resulting types, if there are more than just the default constructor. Instead, try to figure out the use of Dependancy Injection which shall take care of instantiating types for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.net reflection create instance of type` would give you a lot of search results, for example [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)

Usage would be:

```
Sub LoadJobs()
    Dim contracts As New List(Of iOutboundContract)()

    Dim results = From type In System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetTypes()
                  Where GetType(iOutboundContract).IsAssignableFrom(type) AndAlso Not type.IsAbstract AndAlso Not type.IsInterface
                  Select type

    For Each outboundContract In results
        contracts.Add(DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(outboundContract), iOutboundContract))
    Next
End Sub
```

Exclude abstract classes and also interfaces from the results. Otherwise it would give an error. Also make sure the class has a default constructor (otherwise you'll have to use an overloaded method of the `Activator.CreateInstance` method).

Just a slight note; in .NET interfaces generally start with a capital I (i). I would recommend you to also use this convention. I'd rename your `iOutboundContract` (interface) to `IOutboundContract`.

Comment: +1 This is what I meant in my question's comment when I wrote "you shall call for `Activator.CreateInstance` directly, since [...]". No further check is required from there. =)

Comment: Thank you, very impressed with your answer.